# Interpretation of `hidden units` in an RNN Layer (tensorflow,Pytorch)

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

This is a general question for any of the frameworks for both RNN and LSTM.

When we use a Vanilla  or plain networks, for a single layer, such as

`current_layer = torch.nn.Linear(100,125)`  means that there are `125 neurons` 
or a single `weight vector` of 125 units (for each neuron) which change the incoming 100 inputs to 125 outgoing units.

Similarly if `current_layer = torch.nn.Linear(125,100)` says that the incoming 125 inputs will be converted to 100 outgoing vectors.

Now mu question that if I have

```
previous_layer = torch.nn.Embedding(10000,100)
current_layer = torch.nn.RNN(100,125)
```

what does this mean?? What is 100 and 125 shows in the case or RNN? Will there be 100 timestamps as inputs for each time stamps? What does the 125 or `hidden_size` mean in this context then??

Is it going to be a weight vector of 125 units which will be multiplied by the single float (each of the incoming inputs for a total of 100 times?) to produce a `hidden_state`??

Comment: First of all, you cannot claim to have a general question when it is specific to PyTorch. And second, most of your question can be answered by looking at the PyTorch docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.RNN

Comment: Oh okay! and what is the answer than? `PyTorch` does not have the interpretation.